# AngularJS scope propagation of function

Tags: angularjs, function, controller, nested

I have a problem understanding how $scope propagation works.
I have 2 nested controllers :

```
<div ng-controller="ClientCtrl">
   <div class="table-responsive" ng-init="getSocietes()">

     <div style="width: 98%; height: 500px;" ag-grid="gridSocietes" class="ag-blue ag-basic">

     </div>

   </div>
   <div ng-controller="PopupCtrl">
       <script type="text/ng-template" id="pmoPopupConfirmDelete.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
   </div>
</div>
```

The first controller has an ag-grid with some data in it. I need to show a Popup when the user clicks a delete button in order to ask him to confirm deletion of a row in the table.

I'm trying to use the Angular UI Modal controller as it is shown in their homepage.

Thus, I have these 2 controllers :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('SocietesController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams){

$scope.gridSocietes = {

    columnDefs: [
        {headerName: "", field: "", width: 45, suppressSorting: true, suppressResize: true, suppressMenu: true, cellRenderer: actionCellRenderer, suppressSizeToFit: true},
        {headerName: "Société", field: "Societe", cellRenderer: societeCellRenderer, sort: 'asc', filter: 'text'},
        {headerName: "Adresse", field: "Adresse_1", cellRenderer: adresseCellRenderer, filter: 'text'},
        {headerName: "Code postal", field: "CP", width: 100, suppressSizeToFit: true, filter: 'text'},
        {headerName: "Ville", field: "Ville", filter: 'text'},
        {headerName: "Tel", field: "Tel", width: 120, suppressSizeToFit: true, filter: 'text'},
        {headerName: "Fax", field: "Fax", width: 120, suppressSizeToFit: true, filter: 'text'},
        {headerName: "E-mail", field: "Email", filter: 'text'},
        {headerName: "Site Web", field: "Site_Web", filter: 'text'},
        {headerName: "Utilisateurs", width: 100, cellRenderer: usersCellRenderer, suppressSorting: true, suppressResize: true, suppressMenu: true, suppressSizeToFit: true}

    ],
    enableColResize: true,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFilter: true,
    rowSelection: 'single',
    rowData: null,
    angularCompileRows: true
};

$scope.getSocietes = function(){
    $http.get('/api/societes').success(function(response){
        $scope.societes = response;
        $scope.gridSocietes.api.setRowData(response);
        $scope.gridSocietes.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    });
}

$scope.supprimerSociete = function(id, index){
    console.log($scope)
    alert('go');
    openPopup('sm', 'pmoPopupConfirmDelete.html')
    return;
    $http.delete('/api/societes/'+id).success(function(response){
        $scope.societes.splice(index, 1);
        $scope.gridSocietes.api.setRowData($scope.societes);
    });
}

console.log($scope)

}]);
```

And the Popup controller :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('PopupCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

$scope.animationsEnabled = true;

$scope.openPopup = function (size, template) {

var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: true,
  templateUrl: 'pmoPopupConfirmDelete.html',
  controller: 'ModalPopupCtrl',
  size: size,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
};

$scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
  $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
};

}]);


// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

myApp.controller('ModalPopupCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {

$scope.items = items;
$scope.selected = {
  item: $scope.items[0]
};

$scope.ok = function () {
  $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
  $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
});
```

I'm trying to understand why the $scope.supprimerSociete function in the first controller does not see the OpenPopup function in the 2nd controller.

I've tried quite a few things but the OpenPopup function never appears in the scope of the 1st controller ( even when I try to call it with $scope.OpenPopup ), whereas everything from the 1st controller appears in the Popup controller when I log $scope in it...

What am I missing there ?

Thx in advance !

Comment: A childScope inherits the functions of the parent, but the parent doesn't know the function of his children.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass your item to delete with resolve during opening of `$uibModal` and then you can pass this item back to the promise with close.

With this you can remove the item in the close callback if `yes` was clicked. To see this in action please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/ow13vr7x/).

It's hard to see why your code isn't working because I can't see the call of `supprimerSociete` and how you controllers are added. I can only guess that the scopes are like this:

- SocietesController (parent scope)

  - ClientCtrl (child)

    - popupCtrl (child of ClientCtrl)

Then if you want to use $scope methods of clientCtrl or PopupCtrl they're of course not there because the parent will not inherit anything from childs. Please read more about [scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) and about [scope inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Also your method call `openPopup` looks strange because there is no such method. If you define a method on `$scope` it have to be called like this `$scope.openPopup()` (if it is availbale in $scope).

If you want the popup reusable I would create a factory for it then you can dependency inject where you need it.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.delete = function (item) {
  console.log('del', item);
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: 'lg',
      resolve: {
        /*items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        },*/
        item: function() {
         // pass item to delete
          return item;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (deleteItem) {
      var index = $scope.items.indexOf(deleteItem);
      
      $scope.items.splice(index,1);
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('demoApp').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, item) {

 $scope.item = item;
 
  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Confirm delete</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure to delete {{item}}?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">Yes</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">No</button>
        </div>
    </script>
    
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item}}
        <button ng-click="delete(item)">
          delete...
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A childScope inherits the functions of the parent, but the parent doesn't know the function of his children.

you should really use more files to achieve this. First and foremost start using directives, and define your functions / variables as a public member of your controllers. 
If you had done this, you would understand in an instant where the logic is flawed: `clientCtrl.openPopup();` is essentially what you've tried doing.

Secondly, [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), all business logic should be transferred to services. A controller shouldn't handle API-requests, it should just ask for data from a service, and display it, and handle all DOM-events. That's all.

```
clientCtrl.openPopup(items)
    > PopupService.openPopup(items);

popupCtrl.opened = PopupService.opened;
popupCtrl.items = PopupService.items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

As it was suggested by @Pjetr, and with the help of Dan Wahlin's page on [Github](https://github.com/DanWahlin/CustomerManager) I used the angular.ui modal as a service and now it works.